Create geospatial PDF in Python
I created a figure in Python with raster and vector data. I can save it to a PDF but I need to save it as a geospatial PDF with metadata like transform and PROJCS to open in apps like Avenza Maps. How can I do that?
I'm using rasterio, Cartopy, GeoPandas and matplotlib to create the image.

gdal geopdf? https://github.com/roblabs/gdal-geopdf uses gdalwarp  to transform correctly https://gdal.org/programs/gdalwarp.html

You can find GDAL Python examples from https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/autotest/gdrivers/pdf.py.
See how SetProjection and SetGeoTransform are used.
For example around line #741
 ds = gdal.Open("tmp/pdf_update_gt.pdf", gdal.GA_Update)
    sr = osr.SpatialReference()
    sr.ImportFromEPSG(4326)
    ds.SetProjection(sr.ExportToWkt())
    ds.SetGeoTransform([2, 1, 0, 49, 0, -1])
    ds = None

